# How could (or why did) Raba follow Rav's stringencies but not his leniencies?

Tags: posek-psak-decisor-ruling, maseches-shabbos, machlokes, amoroim

[*Eruvin* 6 *amud* 2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=447) says someone who follows the stringencies of *Bes Shamay* and of *Bes Hilel* is a fool walking in darkness: rather, it says, one should follow the one or the other, both when it is lenient and when it is stringent.

[*Shabas* 40 *amud* 1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=202) says *Raba* would follow the stringencies of *Rav* but not his leniencies.

How do we understand *Raba*'s actions in light of the *Bavli Eruvin*?

Comment: Wouldn't the basis of your question preclude any single rabbi from ruling with any two different rabbis in any circumstance? Every one should pick one rabbi from a previous generation and rule with him exclusively. Is there something in particular with Rabbah choosing to be stringent like Rav that made you ask this question?

Comment: @user6591 it seems he followed the stringencies of _Rav_ as a rule, not just once or twice, but not his leniencies. That seems like a violation of the principle I cited. I know of no one else who did so; if there is someone, my question would apply to him also.

Comment: But you have no problem with rabbi x ruling haphazardly with rabbi y and rabbi z in any capacity as long as he doesn't choose to follow any one of them specifically to always be stringent. That it's already not like the gemara with B.H. and B.Sh.

Comment: @user6591, correct. Note also that _Raba_'s doing so is more of a problem for me than some _acharon_'s doing so would be.

Answer (score -3):

Following that statement in *Eruvin* is an attempt to understand what it might mean.  One possibility, which appears at the top of *Eruvin 7 amud 1*, is that only when one finds two *tanna*s or two *amora*s that argue in an argument about which *Bes Shamay* and *Bes Hilel* argued does one have to follow one fully, and not partially one and partially the other.  In your case in *Shabas*, perhaps the argument does not line up with any argument of *Bes Shamay* and *Bes Hilel*, thus allowing *Raba* more leeway in his actions.

Comment: I don't see that explanation there. Are you referring to "תרי תנאי ותרי אמוראי דפליגי אהדדי כעין מחלוקת ב״ש וב״ה"? That means (at least according to _Rashi_) any two _tanaim_ or _amoraim_ who argue, the way _BS_ and _BH_ do.

Comment: I read from _Rashi_ "כי היכי דפליגי בית שמאי ובית הלל בדברי מחלוקתן", and understand that as meaning that _BS_ and _BH_ are arguing on their particular _machlokes,_ but I see how you could read that "ן" as meaning "just like _BS_ and _BH_ argue about their own _makhloykesn"._